Implement multiple currencies converter in Laravel
I'm trying to implement currency converter in laravel using

torann/currency package

https://lyften.com/projects/laravel-currency/doc/
installed this package
composer require torann/currency

publish the package
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Torann\Currency\CurrencyServiceProvider" --tag=config
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Torann\Currency\CurrencyServiceProvider" --tag=migrations

then run migration
php artisan migrate

i have to convert from usd to sek and vice versa default currency will be usd
php artisan currency:manage add usd,sek


used OpenExchangeRates.org for getting the exchange rate data


config/currency.php

'api_key' => env('OPEN_EXCHANGE_RATE_KEY'),

For updating the exchange rate in the db
php artisan currency:update -o

Set default currency to USD  in config/currency.php
'default' => env('DEFAULT_CURRENCY', 'USD'),

added CurrencyMiddleware
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Torann\Currency\Middleware\CurrencyMiddleware::class,
        ...
    ],
];

created UserCurrencyMiddleware.php
  public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->get('currency') && ! $request->getSession()->get('currency')) {
            $request->getSession()->put([
                'currency' => 'SEK',
            ]);
          }
          return $next($request);
    }

on my blade.php
currency is converting
 {{ currency(5.99, 'USD', currency()->getUserCurrency()); }}

but i want it to convert it based on  dropdown selection if user changes to USD it should be USD and KR it should be converted to kr.
   <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                    <option value="KR">Kr</option>
   </select>


current db structure:


Any solution Thanks

"Any solution" - to what? you have not explained what is your issue? You say "on my blade.php currency is converting" - so where are you stuck exactly? What is stopping you to "convert it based on dropdown selection"?

@krisgjika Issue is i want to set global currency of my application based on dropdown change event that should change the product price based on currency selection in all places as soon as user changes the dropdown i want to reload the pages with new currency value

create a simple API endpoint that receives the amount, and currency, and returns a response with the converted amount then in select input onChange event call that API with Ajax
here is sample code
controller:

public function convertCurrency(Request $request){
$amount = currency($request->amount, $request->from , currency()->getUserCurrency());

return response()->json(['amount' => $amount ]);
}

route:
Rooute::get("/convert-currency", [SomeController::class,'convertCurrency']);

script:
$('#select').change(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/convert-currency",
    data: { "amount": 20 , "from": $("#select").val() },
    type: "post",
    success: function(data){
       //handle success res
    }
});
});


Thanks for the answer but i'm working on ecommerce site i have to convert all the products price on drop down change can you pls let me know how can i change that price because this way multiple times we have to call ajax method

you can fetch all product with ajax request with params which currency you want to then in controller get your product from model and map to convert corrency and then return product list and in ajax success response update dom as per your requirement

instead of $("#select").val() passing value manually i want to set this value in session or config so that it will be handled globally, because there are multiple pages we have to manage as soon as user changes the dropdown session or config value also change

In your view page controller you get session data and set amount based on that and when user change currency then get user selected value with $("#select").val() and in controller set that value to session so it will load same data after reload

if you want to update the current selected currency for the user, you need to make a post request with the selected currency and update your session.
class CurrencyController extends Controller
{
  public function __invoke(Request $request)
  {
    $request->validate(['currency' => 'required','exists:currencies,slug']);
    $request->session()->put(['currency' => $request->currency]);
    return response()->json(['currency' => $request->session()->get('currency')]);
  }
}

and in you blade file create a form, (don't forget to declare the route):
<form action="{{route('currency.store')}}" method="POST" id="currency-form">
  @csrf
  <select class="form-control">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="KR">Kr</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
// assuming you are using JQuery
$.(`#currency-form`).onChange(function (e) {
  $.post(`{{route('currency.store')}}`, ['currency' => this.value]);
  window.location.reload();
});
</script>


Thanks if there is no currency set on first time page load in session which currency will be loaded

if session does not have a currency, the one you have forced in your UserCurrencyMiddleware will be set
